how to deal with Zig struct strings with variable size
I have the following
const Task = struct {
    id: u32,
    name: [34]u8,
    progress: u8,
};

but for the Task.name declaration I have a probblem which is the length of the name
I could declare it as
    name: [34:0]u8, but how to init it?
or
    name: [34:0]u8 = undefined, is there a memcpy() equivalent in Zig?
or just
    name: [34]u8 = undefined,this only accepts 34 bytes long names
so, what is the best way (I don't have much experience with dynamic memory)

Assuming that the name field is supposed to be a string, ordinarily in Zig you would use a slice of const u8 for strings. You can then use string literals or dynamically build strings as you wish using arrays or allocators for storage. Something like this:
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;

const Task = struct {
    id: u32,
    name: []const u8,
    progress: u8,
};

pub fn main() void {
    const my_task = Task{
        .id = 42,
        .name = "Ultimate Answer",
        .progress = 0,
    };

    print("On the question of \"{s}\"...\n", .{my_task.name});
    print("Universe: {}\n", .{my_task.id});
    print("Humanity: {}\n", .{my_task.progress});

    var another_task = Task{
        .id = 21,
        .name = "",
        .progress = 0,
    };

    print("another_task.name ({s})\n", .{another_task.name});

    another_task.name = "Halfway There!";
    print("another_task.name ({s})\n", .{another_task.name});

    var build_arr = [_]u8{ 'D', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'i', 'c', '.' };
    build_arr[build_arr.len - 1] = '!';
    another_task.name = build_arr[0..];
    print("another_task.name ({s})\n", .{another_task.name});
}

> zig build-exe .\task.zig
> .\task.exe
On the question of "Ultimate Answer"...
Universe: 42
Humanity: 0
another_task.name ()
another_task.name (Halfway There!)
another_task.name (Dynamic!)

Regarding memcpy, Zig has the built in @memcpy, as well as std.mem.copyForwards and std.mem.copyBackwards in the Standard Library. When and how these would be used depends on more specific details about exactly what OP hopes to accomplish.
As a general rule, one should probably try to use slices as in the example code above.

what if I want to add a Task object on runtime,, how should I do it?

@IbrahimOuhamou -- that depends on the specifics of the situation. It could be as simple as keeping an array of Tasks which you maintain and fill at runtime, or you could use an array list.
